# Find the radius of curvature, and the equation of the osculating circle, for the following curve, at any time $t\ge0$:

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can you please help me with this question?

Question: Find the radius of curvature, and the equation of the osculating circle, for the following curve for $t\geq0$.

$r(t) = \sin(\sqrt{e^t+1}) \hat{i} - \cos(\sqrt{e^t+1}) \hat{j} + 0 \hat{k}$

Attempt: 
v = (e^t cos(sqrt(e^t+1))/(2sqrt(e^t+1) i + (e^t sin(sqrt(e^t+1))/(2sqrt(e^t+1)j
|v| = 0.5e^t sqrt(1/e^t+1)

I am not able to calculate the curvature and the equation of the osculating circle

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to tackle the problem in common.  The curve $r$ in question is a curve in the Euclidian plane. Its curvature $\kappa_r$ is the normal component of the acceleration divided by the square of its velocity. Define $J(a,b):=(-b,a)$ to be the rotation by $\pi/2$ as usual. So
$$\kappa_r=\frac{\langle \ddot r,\frac{J\dot r}{\|\dot r\|}\rangle}{\|\dot r\|^2}=\frac{\langle\ddot r,J\dot r\rangle}{\|\dot r\|^3}.$$
That's for the facts.

Let $r\circ\varphi$ be a $C^2$ reparametrization of $r$ with $\varphi'>0$.

In our case $r(t)=\bigl(\sin(t),-\cos(t)\bigr)$ and $\varphi=\sqrt{e^t+1}$; surely $\varphi'>0$. Let's compute $\kappa_{r\circ\varphi}$. The first derivative of $r\circ\varphi$ is $\dot r(\varphi)\cdot\varphi'$ and the second one is $\ddot r(\varphi)\cdot \varphi'^2+\dot r(\varphi)\cdot\varphi''$. Hence
$$\kappa_{r\circ\varphi}=\frac{\langle\ddot r(\varphi)\cdot \varphi'^2+\dot r(\varphi)\cdot\varphi'',J(\dot r(\varphi)\cdot\varphi' \rangle}{\|\dot r(\varphi)\cdot\varphi'\||^3}.$$
Since $v\perp Jv$   and $J$ is linear we have
$$\kappa_{r\circ\varphi}=\frac{\langle\ddot r(\varphi)\cdot \varphi'^2,J(\dot r(\varphi)\cdot\varphi' \rangle}{\|\dot r(\varphi)\cdot\varphi'\||^3}$$
and as $\varphi'>0$ we arrive in

$$\kappa_{r\circ\varphi}=\frac{\varphi'^3\cdot\langle\ddot r(\varphi),J(\dot r(\varphi)\rangle}{\varphi'^3\cdot\|\dot r(\varphi)\|^3}=\frac{\langle\ddot r(\varphi),J(\dot r(\varphi)\rangle}{\|\dot r(\varphi)\|^3}=\kappa_r\circ\varphi,$$
i.e., *reparametrization which preserves orientation doesn't change curvature.* (If $\varphi'<0$ we had arrive in $\kappa_{r\circ\varphi}=-\kappa_r\circ\varphi$.)

From here we're done as $r$ in our case represents the unit circle $S^1$, so $\kappa_r=1$.

Answer (score 0):

the curvature $\kappa(t)$ is $$\dfrac{||\vec{r}'(t)\times\vec{r}''(t)||}{||\vec{r}'(t)||^3}$$ so the radius $\rho$ is $1/\kappa.$ For the equation of osculating circle, note that the vector, with terminal point equal to the center of the osculating circle and initial point equal to the point $\vec{r}(t)$, is parallel to the unit normal vector $\vec{N}(t)$ of $\vec{r}(t).$ In other words, if $(a,b,c)$ is the center of the osculating circle, then $\langle a,b,c\rangle - \vec{r}(t)=\rho\vec{N}(t).$ Thus, once you know the center and the radius of the circle, you may construct the parametric equations of the osculating circle.

Comment: the cross proctude of the first derivative and the second derivative is impossible. i dont't know why